# pyspark dataframe collect_list for overlaping windows, starting at each non null value

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have a following example pyspark dataframe:

```
+----+----------+----+---+
|name|      date|  v1| v2|
+----+----------+----+---+
|   a|2000-01-01|null|0.1|
|   a|2000-01-02|   1|0.2|
|   a|2000-01-03|null|0.3|
|   a|2000-01-04|null|0.4|
|   a|2000-01-05|   2|0.5|
|   a|2000-01-06|null|0.6|
|   a|2000-01-07|null|0.7|
|   b|2000-01-08|null|0.8|
+----+----------+----+---+
```

The dataframe is ordered by columns (*"name"* and *"date"*) in ascending order.
For every non null entry in column *"v1"* I would like to *"collect_list"* of x entries from column "v2" into a new column *"acc"*; starting from a current row where lists may overlap.

An outcome from the above example for e.g. x = 4 rows.

```
+----+----------+----+---+--------------------+
|name|      date|  v1| v2|                 acc|
+----+----------+----+---+--------------------+
|   a|2000-01-01|null|0.1|                null|
|   a|2000-01-02|   1|0.2|[0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]|
|   a|2000-01-03|null|0.3|                null|
|   a|2000-01-04|null|0.4|                null|
|   a|2000-01-05|   2|0.5|[0.5, 0.6, 0.7]     |
|   a|2000-01-06|null|0.6|                null|
|   a|2000-01-07|null|0.7|                null|
|   b|2000-01-08|null|0.8|                null|
+----+----------+----+---+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an index column by using **`monotonically_increasing_id`** and then Divide the **`row_number()`** with `4`.

Finally **`collect_list`** if `v1` is not null for the window `current_row, unboundedFollowing`.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([('a','2000-01-01',None,'0.1'),
('a','2000-01-02',1,'0.2'),
('a','2000-01-03',None,'0.3'),
('a','2000-01-04',None,'0.4'),
('a','2000-01-05',2,'0.5'),
('a','2000-01-06',None,'0.6'),
('a','2000-01-07',None,'0.7'),
('b','2000-01-08',None,'0.8')],['name','date','v1','v2'])

windowSpec = Window.orderBy("mid")
windowSpec2 = Window.partitionBy("wndw").orderBy("mid").rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df = df.withColumn("mid",monotonically_increasing_id()).\
  withColumn("wndw", ceil(row_number().over(windowSpec)/4)).\
  withColumn("acc", when(col("v1").isNotNull(),collect_list(col("v2")).over(windowSpec2)).otherwise(array(lit(None))))

df.show(10,False)

#+----+----------+----+---+------------+----+--------------------+
#|name|date      |v1  |v2 |mid         |wndw|acc                 |
#+----+----------+----+---+------------+----+--------------------+
#|a   |2000-01-01|null|0.1|25769803776 |1   |[null]              |
#|a   |2000-01-02|1   |0.2|60129542144 |1   |[0.2, 0.3, 0.4]     |
#|a   |2000-01-03|null|0.3|94489280512 |1   |[null]              |
#|a   |2000-01-04|null|0.4|128849018880|1   |[null]              |
#|a   |2000-01-05|2   |0.5|163208757248|2   |[0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]|
#|a   |2000-01-06|null|0.6|197568495616|2   |[null]              |
#|a   |2000-01-07|null|0.7|231928233984|2   |[null]              |
#|b   |2000-01-08|null|0.8|266287972352|2   |[null]              |
#+----+----------+----+---+------------+----+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @notNull. This is close but is not addressing the overlap issue, e.g it is not overlapping over values in column *"v2"*, while it mistakenly overlaps over the *"name"* column.